# How can you set the parallelism for a specific ingress for an embedded statefun application

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

I have a custom ingress which for various reasons should be run as a singleton. While I understand how the default parallelism can be set I do not see a way of controlling this for a specific operator or ingress when imbedded.

I have searched the documentation but have yet to find anything related to this.

Comment: I think you have implemented your own source function with this custom ingress. The default parallelism is 1. Do you want to configure parallelism to your source function?

Comment: You are correct. I did implement my own source function. Sadly the default parallelism appears to follow that specified for the job as a whole so I'm still in need of a way of restricting the parallelism on the source function.